# Execute code first! Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

guys I am getting data from Foursquare APi and here is my code below.

But I am getting a nil error at cellForRowAtIndexPath that venueItems is nil

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        // Table View
        self.tableView = UITableView()

        // Location Manager Stuff
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        self.locationManager.delegate = self

        let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

        if status == .notDetermined {
            self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        } else if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse
            || status == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways {
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        } else {
            showNoPermissionsAlert()
        }

        exploreVenues()
    }

    // Func's

    func exploreVenues() {

        guard let location = self.locationManager.location else {
            return
        }
        var parameters = [Parameter.query: "Pubs"]
        parameters += location.parameters()

        let task = self.session.venues.explore(parameters) {
            (result) -> Void in

            if self.venueItems != nil {
                return
            }

            if !Thread.isMainThread {
                fatalError("!!!")
            }

            if let response = result.response {

                if let groups = response["groups"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    var venues = [[String: AnyObject]]()

                    for group in groups {
                        if let items = group["items"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                            venues += items
                        }
                    }

                    self.venueItems = venues
                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } else if let error = result.error, !result.isCancelled() {
                self.showErrorAlert(error)
            }
        }

        task.start()
    }

    // Table View Data source
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if let venueItems = self.venueItems {
            return venueItems.count
        }

        return 10
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! VenueTableViewCell
        // This is where the error occurs
        let item = self.venueItems![(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] as JSONParameters!
        self.configureCellWithItem(cell, item: item!)

        return cell
    }

    func configureCellWithItem(_ cell: VenueTableViewCell, item: JSONParameters) {

        if let venueInfo = item["venue"] as? JSONParameters {
            cell.nameLabel.text = venueInfo["name"] as? String
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell = cell as! VenueTableViewCell

        let tips = self.venueItems![(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]["tips"] as? [JSONParameters]

        guard let tip = tips?.first, let user = tip["user"] as? JSONParameters,
            let photo = user["photo"] as? JSONParameters else {
                return
        }

        let URL = photoURLFromJSONObject(photo)

        if let imageData = session.cachedImageDataForURL(URL) {
            cell.venueImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        } else {

            cell.venueImageView.image = nil

            session.downloadImageAtURL(URL) { (imageData, error) -> Void in
                let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? VenueTableViewCell

                if let cell = cell, let imageData = imageData {
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    cell.venueImageView.image = image
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I am quite new to programming personally I think that the venueItems is nil because the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is being executed first. If this is the error how can I fix it so the code in cellForRowAtIndexpath runs after my venueItems has a value.. or any other more efficient Way?

Comment: Maybe do `if venueItems != nil { // your code }` or fill the array in viewWillAppear

Answer (score 4):

Your `numberOfRowsInSection` returns `10` when `self.venueItems` is nil. `self.venueItems` appears to be nil until your network request finishes so the table view, having been told it has 10 rows to display asks for a cell for each row. You then attempt to force unwrap an optional property (`self.venueItems!`) and crash.

It looks like your `self.venueItems` is an optional for good reason, don't discard that information with a force unwrap (`!`). You could either return `0` rows when this property is nil or initialize it to a non-optional empty array which you could then always ask for its `count`.

In general with this sort of problem you don't want to focus on preventing `cellForRowAtIndexPath` from being called but rather plan for it to be called at any point and return a reasonable result (like reporting that the table has 0 rows) when your background tasks haven't finished yet.

Comment: Jonah is right. One thing you also need to do is to reload your tableView after venueItems has been set using tableView.reloadData()